# Primevue Data table styling not working in Vue3

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, primevue

So I am trying to add grids to my data table using primevue.
But for some reason the table is bot showing grids.
I am following the example given here https://www.primefaces.org/primevue/datatable/dynamiccolumns.

My code is:

```
<template>
  <div class="tableView">
    <DataTable :value="data" showGridlines responsiveLayout="scroll" >
    <Column v-for="col in columns" :field="col.field" :header="col.header" :key="col.field"></Column>
  </DataTable>
  <el-button type="warning" round @click="togtab">Toggle-Table</el-button>
</div>
```

and script tag is as follows:

```
<script>
import DataTable from '../../node_modules/primevue/datatable';
import Column from '../../node_modules/primevue/column';
import ColumnGroup from '../../node_modules/primevue/columngroup';     
import Row from '../../node_modules/primevue/row';  

export default {
  name: 'TableComp',
  props:['data'],
  data() {
      return {
        columns:[]
      };
    },
  components: {
    DataTable,
    Column
  },
  methods: {
 togtab(){
   for (let i=0; i< Object.keys(this.data).length ;i++ ){
      this.columns[i] = {field: Object.keys(this.data[0])[i], header: Object.keys(this.data[0])[i]}
    }
    console.log(this.columns)
 }  
}
}
</script>
```

In the output I can see just the table
[image]
I will be very grateful if someone could let me know what am I doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're importing the PrimeVue CSS dependencies

```
primevue/resources/themes/saga-blue/theme.css       //theme
primevue/resources/primevue.min.css                 //core css
primeicons/primeicons.css                           //icons
```

you're free to choose any theme, they're listed in the [docs](https://www.primefaces.org/primevue/setup), but picking one is required

Comment: Yes I am importing them as well, it's still not working

Comment: same here ... I imported them all ... I got the components and icons .. but classes are not applied ... when checked the primevue.min.css it says `/**
 * The primevue[.min].css has been deprecated. In order not to break existing projects, it is currently included in the build as an empty file.
 */` ... could that be the issue?

Comment: The question and answer are both outdated.  Always follow the latest instructions in the [documentation](https://primevue.org/installation/#theming).  As of today, you only need the theme CSS import

Comment: tbh @yoduh the documentation is a bit misleading.. check the video tutorial at the bottom of the page ... they specifically mention (check the 4:33) the `primevue.min.css` ...  however, your reply here worked well :) linking it here for the others too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77614800/primevue-not-applying-classes-in-vue3-ts/77615092#77615092